# Using the Java StarTeam API, how can I find which revisions of a StarTeam Item have a certain label?

Tags: java, api, label, starteam

I'm using the StarTeam java API (v10.4).

I am having a heckuva time trying to find which *specific* revisions a Label is applied to.  What makes this tricky is that there seems to be no method on the Label object which provides a list of what that label is applied to.

So you (seemingly) need to go backwards and find a list of items that you want to check for a particular Label, e.g.

```
int[] check_these_items = new int[]{ item_to_check.getID() };
int[] labelledItems = myLabel.getLabeledItemIDs(check_these_items)
```

First, that's kind of convoluted because you need to have a Label in the first place when really what I wanted was to get a list of labels attached to a single revision.  But ok, let's go with that for now.  So now I need to find a single revision from the history.  Let's make this simple and say I want to get the third (or fourth) revision:

```
Item specific_child = item_to_check.getHistory()[3];
```

Now the problem is that this new child from history has the same ID (via `getID()`) as the parent so using `getLabeledItemIds(check_these_items)` will return the same labels and essentially, we haven't gotten anywhere.

I did find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812359/finding-past-revisions-of-files-in-starteam-w-net-sdk-c-sharp) related to finding past revisions but it wasn't pertaining to finding labels *on* past revisions.

Of course, I checked [Borland](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2009/en/sdk_documentation/api/com/starbase/starteam/Item.html)'s API documentation but have not come up with the solution.

I know the UI can do it so certainly there is way, I'm just having a time finding it.

Any suggestions even at a high-level would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the **[Item](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2008/en/SDK_Documentation/api/com/starbase/starteam/Item.html)** and the **[Label](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2008/en/SDK_Documentation/api/com/starbase/starteam/Label.html)** at hand, use **[getFromHistoryByLabelID(int)](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2008/en/SDK_Documentation/api/com/starbase/starteam/Item.html#getFromHistoryByLabelID%28int%29)**
to "Returns the specified version of this item based on the given label ID"

Comment: Just looking at my old posts, yes, you're exactly right. I eventually did re-implement a solution along these lines. `int item_rev_at_label = child.getFromHistoryByLabelID(latestLabel.getID()).getRevisionNumber()` and then `if(child.getRevisionNumber() <= item_rev_at_label)`... etc. .  hard to post code in a comment. . !

Answer (score 0):

This still doesn't seem like the right answer, but eventually I had to move on and ended up using a workaround of finding the revision date/time of the label I wanted and then comparing the item revision to that.  So by that type of reverse logic, I was able to check each label attached to the element and find which revisions had that label.